# Argument Labels '(collectionviewlayout:)' do not match any available overloads

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have encountered an error when trying to change the view to a collection view

> error   Argument Labels '(collectionviewlayout:)' do not match any available overloads is shown

please help

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

let mainpagecontrol = mainpagecontroller(CollectionViewLayout : layout)

window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainpagecontrol)
```

Comment: Did you actually copy and paste your real code into the question? The code you posted doesn't match the error message.

Comment: Oh my mistake. I have updated the code. Thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

@Raymond Tay. You did a very minor mistake. Instead of "CollectionViewLayout" it should be "collectionViewLayout". So the only difference is capital C in your code. The updated code is below.

let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

let mainpagecontrol = mainpagecontroller(collectionViewLayout : layout)

window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainpagecontrol)

let me know if it executes. Thanks.